# How to calculate the logarithm of an outer product?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Im tryting to calculate the entanglement entropy of a subsystem:

$$S_\text{ent}=-k\cdot \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_A\log(\rho_A))$$

Let

$$ \rho_A=\vert\uparrow\rangle\langle\uparrow\vert$$

from what I can remember:

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 
    0 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\vert\uparrow\rangle
$$

This would mean that:

$$
\vert\uparrow\rangle\langle\uparrow\vert =
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0 \\
0&0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So, how do I take the log of this matrix? Since its not diagonal I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your time

Comment: That matrix is very much diagonal.

Comment: so the logarithm of that matrix would be the logarithm of the diagonal entries, what do I do with the ln(0)?

Comment: It's multiplied by zero from the $\rho_A$, so the product is zero.

Comment: Take that diagonal entry to be exp(-x)  as x goes to infinity. Evaluate the trace and take the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state $\rho_A$ written above is pure, i.e. $\rho_A=\rho^2_A$ holds. The von-Neumann entropy of a pure state is equal to zero.
Let a denisty matrix be 
$$\rho=\sum p_j |\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$$
with orthonormal $\psi_i$. 
Then the von-Neumann entropy is 
$$S=-\sum p_i \ln p_i.$$

If $\rho$ is pure then one of $p_i\neq 0$  and the others are zero. In this case 
 $S$ becomes zero (assuming $0 \ln 0 =0$).